# combine ggplot facet_wrap with geom_segment to draw mean line in scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

#### Reproducible example

`df` contains grouped_data by `A,B`

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(A=rep(c("good","bad"),each=8),
                 B=rep(c("yes","no"),4),
                 C=sample(1:20,16),
                 stringsAsFactors=F) %>%
                 group_by(A,B)

 #      A     B     C
 #1  good   yes    13
 #2  good    no     2
 #3  good   yes     4
 #4  good    no    18
 # etc
```

`summ` contains summary data for groups `A,B`

```
summ <- df %>%
          summarise(mean = mean(C),
                    median = median(C)) %>%
          gather(variable, value, mean:median)

#      A     B variable value
#1   bad    no     mean 13.50
#2   bad   yes     mean 11.00
# etc
```

#### Question

I'd like to draw the mean and median line for each scatterplot but combined with `facet_wrap`. *I've come across lots of answers to do this when `facet_wrap` is not used.*

I can draw the lines but have an issue with alignment. You can see the problem by running this code

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=B, y=C)) +
  geom_violin() +
  geom_point() +
  geom_segment( data = summ,
    aes(x = as.numeric(interaction(A,B)) - 0.5,
        xend = as.numeric(interaction(A,B)) + 0.5,
        y = value, yend = value, colour = variable ) ) +
  facet_wrap(~A, nrow=1) +
  theme_classic() + 
  theme( axis.text = element_text( size = 14 ),
         axis.text.x = element_text( size = 20 ),
         axis.title = element_text( size = 16, face = "bold" ),
         legend.position="none" )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, all that needs to change is a bit in `geom_segment(...)`. Rather than `as.numeric(interaction(A,B))`, write `as.numeric(as.factor(B)`.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=B, y=C)) +
  geom_violin() +
  geom_point() +  
  geom_segment(data=summ,aes(x = as.numeric(as.factor(B)) - 0.5, 
                   xend = as.numeric(as.factor(B)) + 0.5, 
                   yend = value, 
                   y = value, 
                   colour = variable)) +
  facet_wrap(~A, nrow=1) +
  theme_classic() + 
  theme( axis.text = element_text( size = 14 ),
         axis.text.x = element_text( size = 20 ),
         axis.title = element_text( size = 16, face = "bold" ),
         legend.position="none" )
```

[image]